# Failed network request on Expo Go Android App

Tags: android, react-native, expo, supabase, expo-go

I'm adding the ability to upload an image to a users profile in my expo go app (Referencing this [guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-expo-react-native)). However, I'm running into an issue only on android apps where I'm unable to upload the file to Supabase storage. I'm able to upload an image successfully on iOS simulator + physical devices as well. Using flipper on a development build of my app doesn't seem to give any more information on the request either aside from the fact that it failed. I'll paste the relevant code snippets below:

```
// utils/supabase.js

import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabaseUrl = "****";
const supabaseAnonKey = "****";

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {
  auth: {
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: false,
  }
});
```

```
// components/ImagePicker.js
...
const uploadAvatar = async () => {
    try {
      setUploading(true);
      const photo = {
        uri: image.uri,
        type: image.type,
        name: image.uri
      }

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", photo);
      const fileExt = image.uri.split('.').pop();
      const filePath = `${Math.random()}.${fileExt}`;

      console.log("UPLOADING AVATAR...");
      const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from('avatars').upload(filePath, formData);
      console.log("UPLOADED FILE"); // this log isn't shown due to the network error from the call above thus moving us into the catch block
      if (error) throw error;

      updateProfile({...});
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error.message);
    } finally {
      setUploading(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        marginT-10
        borderRadius={4}
        label={ uploading ? "Uploading..." : "Upload" }
        onPress={uploadAvatar}
        disabled={uploading}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

```
// package.json dependencies
"dependencies": {
  "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
  "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
  "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.39.3",
  "expo": "~49.0.15",
  "react-native": "0.72.6",
  "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
  "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
  "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
},
```

Again, this works on iOS as expected but not on Android devices. Not really sure how to debug this further.

Comment: From the docs: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-upload: For React Native, using either Blob, File or FormData does not work as intended. Upload file using ArrayBuffer from base64 file data instead, see example below.